# io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors

Tags: java, postgresql, quarkus

Getting this error when i run ./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native

in application.yml file
in

```
datasource:
 db-kind: postgresql
 driver: org.postgresql.Driver
 username: username
 password: password

 jdbc:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres_host_name:port/data_basename
      max-size: 10
```

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to find a JDBC driver corresponding to the database kind 'postgresql' for the default datasource. Either provide a suitable JDBC driver extension, define the driver manually, or disable the JDBC datasource by adding 'quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false' to your configuration if you don't need it.
        at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.resolveDriver(AgroalProcessor.java:330)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.getAggregatedConfigBuildItems(AgroalProcessor.java:276)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.build(AgroalProcessor.java:82)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:944)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

After getting this error i inserted `driver: org.postgresql.Driver`

```
> io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: quarkus.datasource.url and quarkus.datasource.driver have been deprecated in Quarkus 1.3 and removed in 1.9. Please use the new datasource configuration as explained in https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource.
        at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.build(AgroalProcessor.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:944)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

Any suggestions for this

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have configuration properties coming from another source such as environment variables, an application.properties or a `.env` file?

Because Quarkus is complaining about `quarkus.datasource.url` being present and you don't have it in your YAML file. So it must come from somewhere else.

Something like that should be enough if you have the `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql` extension around:

```yaml
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: postgresql
    username: username
    password: password
    jdbc:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres_host_name:port/data_basename
      max-size: 10
```

Comment: I don't have application.properties file.  quarkus-jdbc-postgresql this extension has in build.gradle file. like this 
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql'

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error during a Quarkus course and I fixed it by adding some configs...

**So the error message is giving us 3 options**:

> Build step io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to find a JDBC driver corresponding to the database kind 'postgresql' for the default datasource. **Either provide a suitable JDBC driver extension, define the driver manually, or disable the JDBC datasource** by adding 'quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false' to your configuration if you don't need it.

So I manually added this `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver` to my `application.properties`.

**In your case I believe you have to update your file to this:**

```yaml
datasource:
 db-kind: postgresql
 # driver: org.postgresql.Driver
 username: username
 password: password

 jdbc:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres_host_name:port/data_basename
      driver: org.postgresql.Driver
      max-size: 10
```

*Note:* In addition to that I also added the `quarkus-agroal` dependency to my `pom.xml` file and set the hibernate dialect, with this: `quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect`.